# Why keydown not working in mobile? vue.js 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I try like this :

```
<template> 
    ...
    <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="quantity" min="1" v-on:keydown="disableDot">
    ...                           
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        ...
        methods:{
            disableDot: function(evt) {
                evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event
                let charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
                if (charCode === 190 || charCode === 189 || charCode === 187) {
                    evt.preventDefault()
                } 
                else {
                    return true
                }
            }

        }
    }
</script>
```

If the code executed and I input dot(.), it still can

In dekstop, it had disable. But in mobile, it does not disable

I want to disable dot. So user can not input dot

How can I do it?

**Note**

In dekstop, the code works. But in mobile, the code does not works. The dot(.) no disable in mobile

Answer (score 4):

The trouble is that the keycodes with 'keydown' or 'keyup' dont seem to be consistent across browsers.  Maybe the OS has an affect as well.  You can test this on various browsers and mobile devices [here](http://unixpapa.com/js/testkey.html)

I think you will find more consistency using the `v-on:keypress` event instead. The following in my quick (incomplete on mobile) testing returns '46'  consistently. A quick warning, I noticed that typing '.' on firefox mobile on my android keyboard  I was receiving two keypress events.

```
//in template
<input type="number"  v-on:keypress="capturePress($event)">

//in methods
capturePress: function(event) {
    console.log(event.charCode);
}
```

I would also encourage you to have a look at the whole event as it also returns. `event.code = "Period"` and `event.key = "."` though only `event.key = "."` was filled on mobile firefox.

```
console.log(event);
```

Comment: 'keypress' event is deprecated
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event

Answer (score 0):

Using a watcher worked the best for me. It would be something like this:

```
<template> 
    ...
    <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="quantity" min="1">
    ...                           
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        ...
        methods:{
            disableDot: function(evt) {
                evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event
                let charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
                if (charCode === 190 || charCode === 189 || charCode === 187) {
                    evt.preventDefault()
                } 
                else {
                    return true
                }
            }

        }

        watch: {
          "quantity"(value) {
            this.disableDot();
          }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the real issue with android device ,
You should make disable the autocomplete of your form like this:

> ```
>  <form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
> ```